# Guardar imágenes en mongoDB y luego mostrarlas en la plantilla

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, archivo, angular6

Quiero guardar imágenes en mongoDB. He estado documentandome y todo lo que he visto ha sido para subir imágenes a la BD con un botón upload. Yo busco ingresar las imágenes directamente en la BD. He intentado pegar el nombre del archivo de la imagen en el objeto JSON de la BD, pero claro, me devuelve el texto por la petición Ajax. Aún así me he creado una carpeta que se llama "uploads" y de ahí he extraído las imágenes con el siguiente código.

controlador.js

```
getImageFile: function(req,res){
    var file=req.params.image;
    var path_file='./uploads/'+file;

    fs.exists(path_file,(exists)=>{
      if (exists) {
        return res.sendFile(path.resolve(path_file));
      }else{
        return res.status(200).send({
          message:"No existe la imagen..."
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Imágenes</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <section id="content">
      <!-- <div *ngIf="!word" style="text-align:center">
        <img  [style.backgroundImage]="'url(assets/img/cuenta.gif)'" [style.width.px]="400"
        [style.height.px]="300"/>
      </div> -->
      <div class="list-words">
        <img src="{{url+'get-image/'+image}}" *ngIf="image"/>
      </div>
      <!-- audio -->
      <app-audio></app-audio>
    </section>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

COMPONENT TS

```
getImages(){
    this._wordService.getImages().subscribe(
      response => {
        if(response.images){

          this.image=response.images[0].image;

        }
        console.log(response.images[0].image);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Router.js

```
router.get('/get-image/:image', WordController.getImageFile);
```

Muchas gracias y saludos

Comment: ¿Y la pregunta cuál es? Lo ideal es guardar las imágenes por separado y en la base de datos guardar *solo* el nombre o la ruta a la imagen correcta....

Comment: Pues que si hay alguna manera de guardar las imágenes directamente en el JSON de mongoDB. Sí, he guardado las imágenes en una carpeta dentro del backend que se llama 'uploads' y a traves del router lo muestro. Ese router lo pongo en el JSON, pero cuando hago la petición Ajax, me devuelve solo el router. Y mi duda era esa, como puedo convertir esa ruta que si la pongo en el navegador, si me muestra la imagen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que te ocurre a ti me paso a mi pero no usaba Angular, lo solucione de la siguiente forma:

- Guardaba la imagen fisica en el equipo donde realizas las consultas a MongoDB.
- En MongoDB lo que guardo es un string con la ruta donde esta ubicada la imagen (ej: "/home/imagenes/image.jpg")
- Para enviar la imagen lo que encontré es el modulo de Npm 'Sharp' (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) que puede transformar la imagen a tamaños diferentes y formatos diferente con la gran ventaja de que te devuelve la imagen en un buffer, formato que se puede enviar al frontend y mostrarse.

En resumen, cuando tú realizas una petición al backend, el obtendrá la ruta en MongoDB, con la ayuda de Sharp manipulas la imagen que tienes guardada en la ruta de la maquina y la enviar como buffer.

Espero que esto te pueda ayudar a resolver el problema.

Saludos